# Trying to update UI from background thread: Why does it sometimes throw and sometimes just do nothing?

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading

I've noticed in WPF that when trying to update the UI from a background thread (I know that you're not supposed to do this - just playing around with things) that sometimes it throws an InvalidOperationException, and sometimes it just does nothing. I first noticed this when I was improperly trying to update the UI from a background thread started by an async WCF call (using Begin/End, not the eventing model that automatically marshals to the UI thread).

For example, let's say I've got a simple form with a button and a checkbox. This code will throw an InvalidOperationException ("The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.") every time:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    new Thread(() => checkBox1.IsChecked = true).Start();
}
```

Now, take the same form, and add a bog-standard service reference to a simple WCF service somewhere. Then try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var client = new MyServiceClient();
    //Note the use of Begin/End as opposed to the eventing model - Callback
    //will not be called on the UI thread, but a worker thread. I have
    //verified this through the debugger thread list and by checking the 
    //result of Dispatcher.CheckAccess() in the callback.
    client.BeginMyServiceMethod("MyArgument", Callback, null);
}

private void Callback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    //If I call Dispatcher.CheckAccess() here, it returns false,
    //but if I call Dispatcher.VerifyAccess() it does not throw!
    checkBox1.IsChecked = true;  // no exception, no effect
}
```

My understanding is that a call to Dispatcher.VerifyAccess() in that callback method should throw, as should trying to manipulate anything on checkBox1. Instead, nothing happens - the checkbox in the UI does not become checked, and no exception is thrown. Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: You might put a `try/catch` around that call in the last sample and see if it's throwing an exception. It could be that the WCF service invoker is swallowing exceptions.

Comment: @Jim: Yep, that was it. Please post as the answer. I didn't even think about the fact that the callback originated from framework code that I couldn't see and that was trapping the exception. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that the Framework code that's making the call to the callback method is swallowing exceptions? Put a `try/catch` in the callback to see if exceptions are being thrown. If so, then you know that the Framework is swallowing exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

In general, most GUI environments do not support(and those that do even discourage) you from manipulating widgets from different threads.  Typically there is only 1 thread handling a given GUI.  Most GUI kits supply a mechanism by which you can invoke a 'task' on the gui thread and thus manipulate the widgets safely.  It gets to be an exercise in tedium to create a new task for each tweek of a widget that you wish to do, but there really isn't an alternative.

For C# and wpf(it's been a little while) I believe the mechanism revolves around:

```
widget.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate, args[])
```

So for each tweek of a widget you wish to do, you create a delegate to perform that tweek, and then invoke it through the widgets Dispatcher(the object that handles the dispatching of events on the widgets gui thread).

### References

[BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke.aspx)

Comment: RIGHT but different.   _BeginInvoke_ will invoke your delegate asynchronously(i.e. it will put your delegate on the dispatchers queue and return immediately).  By contrast _Invoke_ will execute synchronously (i.e. put it on the queue, and wait for it to be executed and then return).  Both will work just be mindful of the nuances.